# How do I SELECT multiple values from a function into separate columns?

Tags: sql, postgresql, set-returning-functions

Here is the query I have

```
SELECT
    *
FROM (
    SELECT 
        getlatlng("geom")
    FROM
        mytable
) AS subquery;
```

which returns

```
(-121.9,36.4)
(-117.1,32.9)
(-121.9,36.5)
(-71.2,42.6)
```

I'd like to write

```
SELECT
    subquery.lat, subquery.lon 
FROM (
    SELECT 
        getlatlng("mygeom")
    FROM
        mytable
) AS subquery;
```

and have it return

```
lat  | lon
-------------
36.4 | -121.9
32.9 | -117.1
36.5 | -121.9
42.6 | -71.2
```

Here are the relevant bits of the function.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION getlatlng(geom geometry, OUT longitude text, OUT latitude text)
 RETURNS record
 LANGUAGE sql
 IMMUTABLE
AS $function$
SELECT ...;
$function$
```

Comment: Does Postgresql have a concept of returning a table?

Comment: @JacobH I believe so, I'm still somewhat of a Postgres noob though so take that with a grain of salt. Also I should have mentioned I can't change the function since it's used in a bunch of other places in the codebase.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
SELECT (p).longitude, (p).latitude FROM (
    SELECT getlatlng("mygeom") p 
      FROM mytable
) subquery
```

The `OUT` parameters of the function define the columns of the record returned.

[Example fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=575868bc6888382af51826b2409a8ed8).

Comment: Edited with correct answer, sorry about the confusion!

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe Oh I'm sorry, have you tried it? No? Then maybe don't downvote. OUT parameters of the function serve as the definition of record columns. [Here you go, see it for yourself](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=575868bc6888382af51826b2409a8ed8).

Comment: I did not see the `OUT` parameters. Apologies, my mistake.